# Does fetch in Node.js proceed to download body if I don't ask for it explicitly?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I cannot find a straightforward answer: If I don't wait for response body, does `fetch` still fetch it in the background?

Take this code:

```
const response = await fetch(url);

if (!response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('text/html')) {
  // TODO confirm that we are not proceeding to fetch the body
  return {
    body: '',
    headers: response.headers,
    statusCode: response.status,
    url: response.url,
  };
}

const body = await response.text();
```

Is [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) going to still download body (just in the background) if I don't call `await response.text()`?

> Note: I want to get only headers of non-HTML response. Using HEAD is non-option.

Comment: You'll probably have to check the implementation for that - I don't think it will explicitly stop, at best it will start buffering and apply backpressure. You should however be able to abort the request (and close the connection) after reading the headers with an [AbortSignal](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#class-abortsignal).

Comment: "*Using HEAD is non-option*" - why not? It is absolutely the appropriate solution for this. Fix the server side if there's a problem with HTTP.

Comment: Because it is not my backend.

Comment: Still, if it does not respond correctly to HEAD requests that is a bug that should be reported and fixed

Comment: I'm not really sure it really matters what `fetch()` is doing in this situation.  The server will have already sent the response (or started to send it if it's large) and at least some of it will have come down the network pipe to the underlying TCP OS layer and it will keep coming down the pipe until the TCP layer applies flow control so that depends upon the buffer sizes in the OS layer.  Whether or not the `fetch()` call actually reads it, the body data is already on it's way to you and is already being buffered.

Comment: So, as Bergi said, the only real answer here is to get the target server to support HEAD or some other request that gets you what you want without the target server sending the body in the first place.  In other words, even if `fetch()` isn't reading any of the body yet, the body data is still on its way to the client.  So, maybe flow control happens sooner if `fetch()` isn't reading any of it, but some of it is arriving either way - so its inefficient for what you're trying to do no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to [Undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici) (what node uses under the hood for fetch), yes, data is buffered behind the scenes in that implementation for performance.

If you're referring to `node-fetch`, or any of the other many libraries that provide similar functionality: I haven't looked, but I'm very confident that they also buffer data behind the scenes.

The question of "does it matter" or "what should I do" is another question entirely, which should be answered in another post, in the comments, or off of SO.